# how to get a wfs feature from coordinates in geotools

Tags: java, geotools

I'm working on web services in Java and using GeoTools java api for wfs operations.

I have a wfs store and a lot of features in it. I do some operations via geotools wfs api for example buffer, intersect etc. My problem is not building feature from points. I'm using geotools for building my geo web services and want to create a web service method that must use two parameters(lat and lon) and return content of a feature.

This returned feature must be perfectly matched with given latitude and longitude so this coordinates should point out this feature

How can I do that ? Thanks in advance.